# How to insert a variable in a closure for PHP?

Tags: php

```
function updateParameters($landing)
{
    $addValue = function ($final,$parametername,$value)
    {
        $value1=str_replace (  '{landing}' ,  $landing ,$value );
        $_GET[$parametername]=$value1;
        return "";
    };

    doSomethingWith20Params($addValue, "")  ;
}
```

Basically, `$addValue` is a function. The parameter number cannot be changed. That's because `doSomethingWith20Params ($addValue, "");` requires a function with 3 parameters.

In PHP I got

```
5   446.6299    486504  doSomethingWith20Params( ???, ???, ??? )    ...\cutoolsgeneral.php:204
6   552.2776    487112  {closure:H:\business\shared\Dropbox\htdocs\tools2\cutoolsgeneral.php:197-202}( ???, ???, ??? )  ...\cutoolsgeneral.php:188
```

Comment: Why can't you change the number of parameters? First you define it yourself and second you can create a function with dynamic number of parameters. Or you can use the `use` notation if that third parameter is a fixed thing.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `use` keyword, to bind vars to your closure

```
function updateParameters($landing)
{
    $addValue = function ($final,$parametername,$value) use ($landing)
    {
        $value1=str_replace (  '{landing}' ,  $landing ,$value );
        $_GET[$parametername]=$value1;
        return "";
    };

    doSomethingWith20Params($addValue, "")  ;
}
```